# I overstayed in UK for 15 months.Will my overstay affect my USA Spouse visa process?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, overstay, refusal

I overstayed in UK for 15 months, because I was misguided by my immigration Lawyer. Now I am applying for a spouse visa to USA. Will my overstay affect my USA visa process?

Comment: By "spouse visa", you mean an immigrant visa for a spouse immigrating as the spouse of a US citizen or permanent resident, right?

Comment: Yes. I am getting married to a USA Green Card Holder. Will my overstayed affect my new visa process?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't have any effect on getting an immigrant visa to the US.

Comment: Can you please include any sources why you think it's okay?

Comment: @SztupY: There is simply no inadmissibility that this could involve. For example, they could not have issues with being suspected of having immigrant intent, because, well, they are immigrating.